# How to create an empty ios project in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

i'm using xcode 6 and they no longer have the "empty project" option when creating a new project, only a single view one...Is there an option to get it or it's gone and I need to deal with it?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deal with it, but it's easy. Start with the Single View application. Delete the storyboard and delete the reference to it in the Info.plist (so that there is no longer a main storyboard). If you like, delete the view controller class as well. Now just do everything from scratch in the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption:`, just as you did in Xcode 5.

I'm using Swift these days, so I'll show you what a pure code app delegate launch looks like in Swift; I'm sure you can translate into Objective-C:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window : UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController() // or whatever you call it
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man. some weird stuff in xcode 6 though...for example, I have a project i created using xcode 5 that when i created it i checked the "use core data" button and it automatically import the coredata framework for me, but in 6 I had to manually import it even though I checked the "use core data" button. and also when I created a class to represent the core data stack, I had to import core data in the header file to write core data code...which before i could just write it..!

Comment: @rockNroll If you have a use case where stuff "just worked" in Xcode 5 and now it doesn't, file a bug report with Apple!